# How do I use python requests to download a processed files?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm using Django 1.8.1 with Python 3.4 and i'm trying to use requests to download a **processed** file. The following code works perfect for a normal request.get command to download the exact file at the server location, or unprocessed file. 
 The file needs to get processed based on the passed data (shown below as "data"). This data will need to get passed into the Django backend, and based off the text pass variables to run an internal program from the server and output .gcode instead .stl filetype.

python file.

```
import requests, os, json

SERVER='http://localhost:8000'
authuser = 'admin@google.com'
authpass = 'passwords'

#data not implimented
##############################################
data = {FirstName:Steve,Lastname:Escovar}
############################################ 

category = requests.get(SERVER + '/media/uploads/9128342/141303729.stl', auth=(authuser, authpass))

#download to path file
path = "/home/bradman/Downloads/requestdata/newfile.stl"
if category.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in category:
            f.write(chunk)
```

I'm very confused about this, but I think the best course of action is to pass the data along with request.get, and somehow make some function to grab them inside my views.py for Django. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you can send as GET or POST - it depends what you have in django code.

Comment: How do I modify my "category" item to accept the "data" variable, and how will it show on the Django side?

Comment: `category` keeps result/response, not request - you can't change it. Use `get( ... , params=data)` or `post( ... , data=data)`. Read [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.  The more I've been looking into this, python-requests is much more limited then I thought. My real issue is in Django and where the get function is called from Django Rest Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `data` in request you can do

```
get( ... , params=data)
```

(and you get data as parameters in url)

or

```
post( ... , data=data).
```

(and you send data in body - like HTML form)

BTW. some APIs need `params=` and `data=` in one request of GET or POST to send all needed information.

Read [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)